# Did Holly violate the don't enter a human's home unless invited rule in "The Time Paradox"?

Tags: artemis-fowl, artemis-fowl-the-time-paradox

In the *Artemis Fowl* series, fairies are not allowed to enter a human home unless specifically invited to do so. The method of invitation can vary significantly, but it still exists.

In between *Artemis Fowl: the Time Paradox* and *Artemis Fowl: the Lost Colony* this rule

> is eventually removed.

However, in *Artemis Fowl: the Time Paradox*, Holly and Artemis

> go back in time, to a time before this restriction is in place.

Holly enters several human buildings, including the compound of the Extinctionists, without any permission.

> It seems like this is a violation of Fairy Law at the time, but no mention of this is ever made. The same thing could be said of Opal.

Am I going crazy, did the limits not affect her because of the time travel, or is there something else I'm missing entirely?

Comment: Where did she enter a compound without permission?  Being that Kronski *wanted* her there (albeit as merchandise to be used for nefarious purposes), that would be counted as having permission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the spell only affects fairies entering *dwellings*, not buildings. Holly entered the restaurant and fought a troll in the very first book the very first time we encountered her, with no ill effects.

Secondly, fairies *can* enter dwellings without permission, it’s just they get violently sick and lose their magic.

Now, if Holly DID break this rule in *The Time Paradox* (and I don’t recall offhand that she did enter an actual dwelling), she might have been temporarily immune because she was charged up with Number One’s demon warlock magic. It was the demon warlocks that cast the global spell that put that restriction in place.

Comment: No, Holly needed explicit permission to enter the restaurant, and even there she was stretching the law (a child cried “aiuto” which she interpreted as an invitation), and almost got into trouble because of it.

Comment: Similarly, she needed permission to enter Taipei 101 during *The Eternity Code* (which she got from some random plaque saying "welcome" or something along those lines).

Answer (score 11):

> This rule is eventually removed, in between "The Time Paradox" and "The Lost Colony".
>
> Holly enters several human buildings, including the compound of the Extinctionists, without any permission. It seems like this is a violation of Fairy Law at the time

I’m assuming that, because that Holly is from the future, future law applies to her. Remember the spell is on the fairies, not on the buildings. On the other hand, the books usually explain such intricacies. The fact that they didn’t do so here points to a logic error.

> The same thing could be said of Opal.

Indeed; but only as this is the *past* version of Opal who hasn’t forfeited her magic. Remember, the future version got rid of her magic deliberately so the restriction on entering human buildings no longer applies to her.

But yes, the fact that past Opal can apparently enter human buildings has no in-Universe explanation.

Comment: When does past Opal enter a building?  Present-day Fowl Manor?